# Update Vendor Class while creating new or updating existing Vendor

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to update Vendor Class while creating new or updating existing vendor using code. However, I am getting below error--

"Error: An error occurred while processing the field Class ID value SERVICES   Error: Class ID `'SERVICES'` cannot be found in the system.."

Below is the code snippet

```html
VendorR row1 = null;
VendorMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<VendorMaint>();

row1 = new VendorR();

row1 = graph.BAccount.Insert(row1);

row1.VendorClassID = "SERVICES";

graph.BAccount.Update(row1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is definitely related to VendorClass and only those values are displayed in the lookup. However, to update the VendorClass, it is few steps to update it.

I figured out the answer. I called CopyAccounts method from VendorMaint class which updates the VendorClass along with the several related fields as necessary. I have tested it and it is updating the VendorClass properly.

Thank you.
Krunal

Comment: Above solution works in my local system but not on another development system. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Considera the file "Your_Acumatica_Installation"\App_Data\CodeRepository\PX.Objects\AP\DAC\Vendor.cs" Near VendorClassID you can find declaration, which says, that it can have only values from VendorClass table, field vendorClassID. I mean (Search2). I assume that in that table there is not any field, which is equal to "SERVICES"